# Почему при запуске приложения на expo выводятся ошибки?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

Я делаю приложение на react-native и expo. Не могу разобраться уже 3 часа. Я пишу expo start и когда я открываю приложение на своем устройстве, и оно начинает запускаться, но выводятся эти ошибки.
Код из App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ApolloProvider from 'react-apollo';
import ThemeProvider from 'styled-components';
import { Platform, StatusBar }  from 'react-native';
import  AppLoading from 'expo';
import * as Icon from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Asset  from 'expo-asset';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import setupApolloClient from './config/setup';
import Colors from './constants/Colors';
import  Bg  from './components/styled';
import  {theme, ThemeContext } from './config/theme';

const _makeTheme = (type = 'light') => ({
    color: Colors,
    ...theme(type)
});
const dark = _makeTheme('dark');
const light = _makeTheme('light');

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
    apolloClient = null;
    state = {
        isLoadingComplete: false,
        hasHydrated: false,
        theme: 'light'
    };

toggleTheme = () => {
    this.setState(
        ({ theme }) => ({
            theme: theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
        }),
        this._changeStatusBarStyle
    );
};

_changeStatusBarStyle = () => {
    StatusBar.setBarStyle(
        this.state.theme === 'light' ? 'default' : 'light-content'
    );
};

componentDidMount() {
    return Platform.OS === 'ios' && this._changeStatusBarStyle();
}

render() {
    const { isLoadingComplete, hasHydrated } = this.state;

    if (!isLoadingComplete && !hasHydrated) {
        return ( <
            AppLoading startAsync = { this._loadResourcesAsync }
            onError = { this._handleLoadingError }
            onFinish = { this._handleFinishLoading }
            />
        );
    } else {
        return ( 
            <ApolloProvider client={this.apolloClient}>
            <ThemeContext.Provider
              value={{ theme: this.state.theme, toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme }}
            >
              <ThemeProvider theme={this.state.theme === 'light' ? light : dark}>
                <Bg forceInset={{ bottom: 'never', top: 'always' }}>
                  <AppNavigator />
                </Bg>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
          </ApolloProvider>
        );
    }
}

_loadResourcesAsync = async() => {
    this.apolloClient = await setupApolloClient();

    return Promise.all([
        Asset.loadAsync([
            require('./assets/images/buymeacoffee-logo.png'),
            require('./assets/images/youtube-logo.png'),
            require('./assets/images/brain.png')
        ]),
        Font.loadAsync({
            // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
            ...Icon.Ionicons.font,
            // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free
            // to remove this if you are not using it in your app
            'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
            Menlo: require('./assets/fonts/Menlo-Regular.ttf')
        })
    ]);
};

_handleLoadingError = error => {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
    // reporting service, for example Sentry
    console.warn(error);
};

_handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true, hasHydrated: true });
};
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите код который в App.js

Comment: Только что заметил, что не добавил его